# Chart of the Rishonim?

Tags: product-recommendation, rishonim, acharonim, rebbe-talmid-muvhak

Does anyone know if there is a chart of the Rishonim available? Like a genealogy tree (but for rav/talmid and by region).

If it goes on to Acharonim, even better.

I have one for the Tannoim and Amoroim and find it most useful to remember seniority and schools of thought etc.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Etzbah, I hope you enjoy our community. If you don't mind, I've taken the liberty of adding the [product-recommendation] and [rebbe-talmid-muvhak] tags to your post to make it easier to find.

Comment: Thanks Noach. I wanted to add 'chart' and 'timeline' but it wouldn't let me. Kol tuv

Comment: Here's a Rambam chain: Rav Hai Gaon, Rav Nissim Gaon, Rif, Ri Migash, R. Maimon, Rambam, Rabbenu Avraham, Rav David HaNagid, R. Avraham HaNaggid II, R. Yehoshua HaNaggid, R. David HaNaggid II.

Comment: Here's a rough Tosafist one: Rashi, R. Meir ben Shemuel, Rashbam, Rabbenu Tam, Ri Hazaken, Rash Mishants, R. Yehudah Sir Leon, R. Yehiel of Paris, R. Meir of Rothenburg, Rosh, R. Ya'akov ben HaRosh.

Comment: And here's one that includes Catalonia: R. Meir ben Sh'muel, Rashbam, Rabbenu Tam, Ri Hazaken, Ritsba, R. Yehudah ben Yakar, Ramban, Rashba, R. Yehushua Ibn Shuib, R. M'nahem Ibn Zerah.

Answer (score 3):

Rav Mordechai Menachem Reich printed out a pretty comprehensive set of charts which are now available in book form at many seforim stores.

The book is called Toras Hadoros, and is described [here](http://www.chinuch.org/static_files/Navi.pdf) as follows:

> Mechanchim often find themselves challenged
>   by historical technicalities in the materials they
>   teach. Whether in חומש ,נביא or Jewish
>   history, there is so much that we need to know
>   – but often have no access to information.
>   Rabbi Reich’s Toras
>   Hadoros is a perfect
>   solution. Rabbi Reich
>   spent years in Eretz
>   Yisroel compiling a set
>   of 20 astoundingly
>   informative charts that
>   present the entirety of
>   Jewish history in clear
>   and detailed fashion.
>   The generations from
>    the until אדם הראשון
>   present – the dynasties
>   of the מלכים ,the legacies of the נביאים and of the גדולה כהונה ,Jewish
>   exile and the התורה מסורת from סיני הר מעמד through the periods of the
>   אמוראים תנאים ,...all the way through the האחרונים תקופת ...it’s all there
>   – with dates, basic biographical and other pertinent information. The
>   encyclopedic resource is highly recommended for all Middle Schools and
>   High Schools (Yeshivos, Mesivtos, Bais Yaakovs) as a vital  library and/or
>   staff-room resource. Oversize book (20” x 14”) format.

See it [here](http://mysefer.com/__p-6672.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks ideal. Have asked Lehmanns if they can source it in the UK.